# Are there reinforcement learning algorithms not based on Markov decision processes?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process

Are all RL algorithms based on the MDP? If not, could you give examples of some which aren't? I've looked elsewhere, but I haven't seen it explicitly said.

Comment: [Here](https://qr.ae/TqUMmk)'s a very interesting answer to the question [What are some alternative learning paradigms besides Markov decision processes?](https://qr.ae/TqUuei). I had also asked a similar question two years ago [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/27010/10640).

Comment: Thank you for your response; that Quora post is pretty interesting.